# jQuery - AJAX unexpected token error when requesting JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: domain + "/do_getmemes.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {userid: userid},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data["0"]["id"]);
    }
});
```

And this the JSON I suppose to get:

```
[{"id":"6","pic":"c0cZvS9M64.jpg","userid":"14","nickname":"pablo jackson"},{"id":"7","pic":"XUulYui831.jpg","userid":"14","nickname":"pablo jackson"}]
```

But I get this error:

```
[event:[object Object]], [jqXHR:[object Object]], [ajaxSettings:[object Object]], [thrownError:SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 2])
```

What is wrong here? I used AJAX countless times to get json response but that's the first time I get dumb error like that.

This is the last part of PHP file:

```
$array = array();
$x = 0;
while($parse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($anfrage))
{
    echo
    $array[$x]['id'] = $parse['id'];
    $array[$x]['pic'] = $parse['pic'];  
    $array[$x]['userid'] = $parse['memberid'];  
    $array[$x]['nickname'] = $parse['membername'];

    $x++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
file_put_contents('wth.json', json_encode($array));
```

Comment: Your response is not valid JSON. Check your browser's _Network_ console to see the actual response

Comment: How can it be not valid? I used exact this way to retrieve json through AJAX many times before. What am I suppose to see in console network? Everything there is status 200 and there aren't any errors

Comment: You've probably got something else in the output buffer _before_ your `echo json_encode($array)`. Check the actual response to the request (click the request in your _Network_ console and select the _Response_ tab). Whatever is at character position #2 is not a valid JSON token

Comment: oh you are right :D there is an echo inside while which I overlooked while editing, thanks! ^^

Answer (score -1):

alert can't render objects you could `alert( JSON.stringify(data["0"]["id"]) );` or you could just use the `console.log(data["0"]["id"]);` which is a bit more appropriate for the type of data you're trying to look at.

hmm that php should be ok have you set the header correctly for the response?

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: I also tried console.log in the response but I don't get any response at all but the error

Comment: then you might have an issue with the data coming from the php file, whats does the response look like if you just log 'data'

Comment: nothing, blank, I don't get ANY response. I'll add what's in the php file too to the question

Comment: _"alert can't render objects"_  it certainly can, it just doesn't do a very good job. You get _"[object Object]"_

Comment: printing out [object Object] is not rendering an object guys...